# set subtotal value at multiple addresses checkout

Tags: magento2, php, update-subtotal, multiple-checkout

In the multiple address review checkout, there is sub total for each item, like in the picture below. How can I get the subtotal value for each item and change it?

[image: subTotal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer myself, to change the subtotal for each item, we could change it with code like below.

```
$item->setRowTotal($value);
```